# angular rails app not showing data in view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, angularjs

When I go to localhost:3000/main/index, I see nothing, where I should see the blog posts in mainindexCtrl.js.coffee:

I have these files in my assets/javascripts folder:

```
angular-route.min.js
angular.min.js
underscore-min.js
```

**application.js:**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require angular.min
//= require angular-route.min 
//= require underscore-min
//= require_self
//= require_tree ./services/global
//= require_tree ./services/main
//= require_tree ./filters/global
//= require_tree ./filters/main
//= require_tree ./controllers/global
//= require_tree ./controllers/main
//= require_tree ./directives/global
//= require_tree ./directives/main

var app = angular.module('venturelateral', ['ngRoute']);
```

**application.html.erb:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="venturelateral"> 
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Rails3 Bootstrap Devise Cancan" %></title>
    <meta name="description" content="<%= content_for?(:description) ? yield(:description) : "Rails3 Bootstrap Devise Cancan" %>">
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= yield(:head) %>
  </head>
  <body class="<%= controller_name %> <%= action_name %>">
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
      <nav class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <%= render 'layouts/navigation' %>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="main" role="main">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
           <div class="row">
            <div class="span12" ng-view>
              <%= render 'layouts/messages' %>
              <%= yield %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <footer>
          </footer>
        </div>
      </div> <!--! end of .container -->
    </div> <!--! end of #main -->
  </body>
</html>
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails3BootstrapDeviseCancan::Application.routes.draw do

  get "main/index"

end
```

**mainindexCtrl.js.coffee**

```
@IndexCtrl = ($scope) ->
    $scope.data = 
        posts: [{title: 'My first post', contents: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec laoreet lobortis vulputate. Ut tempus, orci eu tempor sagittis, mauris orci ultrices arcu, in volutpat elit elit semper turpis. Maecenas id lorem quis magna lacinia tincidunt. In libero magna, pharetra in hendrerit vitae, luctus ac sem. Nulla velit augue, vestibulum a egestas et, imperdiet a lacus. Nam mi est, vulputate eu sollicitudin sed, convallis vel turpis. Cras interdum egestas turpis, ut vestibulum est placerat a. Proin quam tellus, cursus et aliquet ut, adipiscing id lacus. Aenean iaculis nulla justo.'}, {title: 'A walk down memory lane', contents: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin leo sem, imperdiet in faucibus et, feugiat ultricies tellus. Vivamus pellentesque iaculis dolor, sed pellentesque est dignissim vitae. Donec euismod purus non metus condimentum porttitor suscipit nibh tempor. Etiam malesuada elit in lectus pharetra facilisis. Fusce at nisl augue. Donec at est felis. Sed a gravida diam. Nunc nunc mi, egestas non dignissim et, porta aliquam ante.'}]
```

**app/views/main/index.html.erb**

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="IndexCtrl">
  <h1 class="text-center">My blog</h1>
  <div class="row" ng-repeat="post in data.posts">
      <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
      <p>{{ post.contents }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**main_controller.rb:**

```
class MainController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

Comment: Is the source code empty? Or are you simply not seeing anything in the browser window?

Comment: Why do you use ng-view? I can't find any configuration for angular routes

Comment: I was following a tutorial. I got it to work by including angular-resource and then replaced the bottom line in the application.js file with this: angular.module('venturelateral', ['ngResource'])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ng-view is used when you develop single page application, that is when you want to replace page content without reloading. 
In your case you don't need it. It's just a partial that will be displayed in the middle of the page.
Now if you absolutely want to use ng-view, you should move *render 'layouts/messages'* in a template and configure routes. Ng-view itself should be empty, e.g. *<div ng-view > </div>*. 
For full description about how to configure routes refer to [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.directive%3angView).

Comment: that did the trick. I did figure out how to do it with ng-view though. I included angular-resource.js in the application.js file and instead of this line at the bottom of the application.js file: angular.module('venturelateral', ['ngRoute']); I did this: angular.module('venturelateral', ['ngResource'])